# Use like operator in a custom column in SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-like

i want to use like operator in custom column.
Table contains Name and Surname columns.

---

Could i use something like this ?

```
Select (Name+' '+ Surname) as NS from Customers Where NS like '%mat%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NO, you can't use column alias in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use any operator like this, you would either need to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT (Name+' '+ Surname) as NS 
FROM Customers 
WHERE (Name+' '+ Surname) LIKE '%mat%';
```

Or put your expression in a subquery, then refer to the columns:

```
 SELECT NS
 FROM (SELECT (Name+' '+ Surname) AS NS FROM Customers) AS c
 WHERE NS LIKE '%mat%'
```